# Identify the reason of deadlock

Tags: sql, sql-server, profiling, deadlock

I have 2+ concurrent processes. Inside them there is an iteration that perform repetitive validate (select) + save (insert) operations. Here is the sql-server-profiler info on the deadlock:

```
<deadlock-list>
     <deadlock victim="process8e09048">
      <process-list>
       <process id="process8e09048" taskpriority="0" logused="1088" waitresource="PAGE: 29:1:376823" waittime="920" ownerId="1276429306" transactionname="user_transaction" lasttranstarted="2012-09-26T20:59:44.367" XDES="0x3077833c0" lockMode="S" schedulerid="1" kpid="4872" status="suspended" spid="79" sbid="0" ecid="0" priority="0" trancount="1" lastbatchstarted="2012-09-26T20:59:44.427" lastbatchcompleted="2012-09-26T20:59:44.427" clientapp=".Net SqlClient Data Provider" hostname="PORTAL" hostpid="5348" loginname="IIS APPPOOL\ASP.NET v4.0 Classic" isolationlevel="read committed (2)" xactid="1276429306" currentdb="29" lockTimeout="4294967295" clientoption1="671088672" clientoption2="128056">
        <executionStack>
         <frame procname="adhoc" line="1" stmtstart="282" sqlhandle="0x02000000b79df8046665e3984d6dc129fec20a3029fce9bc">
    SELECT id FROM [WP_CashCenter_StockTransactionLine] WHERE StockTransaction_id=@StockTransaction_id and Direction=@Direction and IsVerified=@IsVerified and QualificationType=@QualificationType and id &lt;&gt; @id and Product_id is null and Material_id=@Material_id and StockContainer_id is null and StockLocation_id=@StockLocation_id     </frame>
         <frame procname="unknown" line="1" sqlhandle="0x000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000">
    unknown     </frame>
        </executionStack>
        <inputbuf>
    (@id bigint,@StockTransaction_id bigint,@Direction int,@IsVerified bit,@QualificationType int,@Material_id nvarchar(3),@StockLocation_id int)SELECT id FROM [WP_CashCenter_StockTransactionLine] WHERE StockTransaction_id=@StockTransaction_id and Direction=@Direction and IsVerified=@IsVerified and QualificationType=@QualificationType and id &lt;&gt; @id and Product_id is null and Material_id=@Material_id and StockContainer_id is null and StockLocation_id=@StockLocation_id    </inputbuf>
       </process>
       <process id="process5c13948" taskpriority="0" logused="2636" waitresource="PAGE: 29:1:376823" waittime="920" ownerId="1276429252" transactionname="user_transaction" lasttranstarted="2012-09-26T20:59:44.337" XDES="0x222e64e80" lockMode="S" schedulerid="6" kpid="2956" status="suspended" spid="70" sbid="0" ecid="0" priority="0" trancount="1" lastbatchstarted="2012-09-26T20:59:44.427" lastbatchcompleted="2012-09-26T20:59:44.427" clientapp=".Net SqlClient Data Provider" hostname="PORTAL" hostpid="5348" loginname="IIS APPPOOL\ASP.NET v4.0 Classic" isolationlevel="read committed (2)" xactid="1276429252" currentdb="29" lockTimeout="4294967295" clientoption1="671088672" clientoption2="128056">
        <executionStack>
         <frame procname="adhoc" line="1" stmtstart="238" sqlhandle="0x02000000d77dd1038a9b7f6d7158436117c042e42767242d">
    SELECT id FROM [WP_CashCenter_StockTransactionLine] WHERE StockTransaction_id=@StockTransaction_id and Direction=@Direction and IsVerified=@IsVerified and QualificationType=@QualificationType and id &lt;&gt; @id and Product_id is null and Material_id=@Material_id and StockContainer_id is null and StockLocation_id is null     </frame>
         <frame procname="unknown" line="1" sqlhandle="0x000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000">
    unknown     </frame>
        </executionStack>
        <inputbuf>
    (@id bigint,@StockTransaction_id bigint,@Direction int,@IsVerified bit,@QualificationType int,@Material_id nvarchar(3))SELECT id FROM [WP_CashCenter_StockTransactionLine] WHERE StockTransaction_id=@StockTransaction_id and Direction=@Direction and IsVerified=@IsVerified and QualificationType=@QualificationType and id &lt;&gt; @id and Product_id is null and Material_id=@Material_id and StockContainer_id is null and StockLocation_id is null    </inputbuf>
       </process>
      </process-list>
      <resource-list>
       <pagelock fileid="1" pageid="376823" dbid="29" objectname="Edsson_WebPortal_v5.01.dbo.WP_CashCenter_StockTransactionLine" id="lock9302c80" mode="IX" associatedObjectId="72057594148028416">
        <owner-list>
         <owner id="process5c13948" mode="IX"/>
        </owner-list>
        <waiter-list>
         <waiter id="process8e09048" mode="S" requestType="convert"/>
        </waiter-list>
       </pagelock>
       <pagelock fileid="1" pageid="376823" dbid="29" objectname="Edsson_WebPortal_v5.01.dbo.WP_CashCenter_StockTransactionLine" id="lock9302c80" mode="IX" associatedObjectId="72057594148028416">
        <owner-list>
         <owner id="process8e09048" mode="IX"/>
        </owner-list>
        <waiter-list>
         <waiter id="process5c13948" mode="S" requestType="convert"/>
        </waiter-list>
       </pagelock>
      </resource-list>
     </deadlock>
    </deadlock-list>
```

[image]

The statements are selects with conditions. The where clause of these selects only uses columns that are included to non-clustered index. Execution plan:
[image]

Comment: Your transaction has IX locks, it means there were updates, deletes or inserts done by the transaction prior to this SELECT.

Comment: Stack Overflow is a Question and Answer board, not a problem solving machine. If you want help you'll need to form this into a question: Explain the problem, explain what you are trying to do, explain what you've tried to rectify it, and then ask a question. You'll probably find you "Rubber duck" the answer along the way.

Comment: @RemusRusanu yes, these is a cycle with validate (select) + insert.
And there are 2+ concurrent processes that are performing this cycle.

Comment: @MichaelAllen, which kind of additional info do you need?

Comment: Just add with(udplock) hint to your select statements.

Comment: @Arvo i know abou this hint. Are there any other solutions? And i'd like to know why such things happen in more detail. I've just got rid of the range-key-locks deadlocks in awhile almost in the same place. And now i get another type of deadlocks. In the same method! This is just making me crazy.

Comment: Other solutions? Don't use transactions or design your transactions in a way, when all updates and inserts are placed before selects. I don't know more good solutions; we have got rid of all our deadlocks this way. Why these things happen? Select1 places shared lock S1, select2 places shared lock S2 to same page. Insert1 places Intent eXclusive lock IX1, this will be wait for releasing S2 - but Insert2 places IX2 lock, which will wait for releasing S1 - deadlock occurs. Using (updlock) hint places IX lock instead of S and already select will be waiting for other transaction to complete.

Comment: The scenario you described refers to range-locks of keys, not page-locks. The victims of deadlocks are insert statemet, not selects. You are wrong. And, btw, if you got rid of all of your deadlock using this hint, then i congradulate you: you've chosen the least optimal solution of all possible.

Comment: Possible solutions.
1. An index that covers the select statement.
2. RCSI
3. ROWLOCK hint on SELECT

Comment: 1. There is an appropriate index (look at the execution plan. No key-lookups) 2. I am currently using RC level. Does that really make any difference from the RCS in my case? Is there any potential danger (or side-effects) of switching to RSC? 3. Tested different lock hints and that dramatically impacted the performance. PS: you'd better post and answer rather then comment so that i could vote for it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this deadlock graph, both the processes were succeeded performing the INSERT and is holding the IX lock on the same page. They must be holding an X lock also on a two separate rows in the same page.

Since the SELECT is covered by the NC index, the page involved in the deadlock must be belonging the NC Index.

Your SELECT statement is trying to acquire a page level lock which is already having an IX lock by the INSERT statements.

So if your INSERTs are not belonging to the same StockTransaction_id, just adding the ROWLOCK hint to the SELECT will resolve the deadlock condition.

RCSI guarantees that readers are not blocked by writers and vice versa. But if your application design is relying on any blocking behavior, this can be an issue.

You can read more about Deadlock due to different lock granularity [here](http://sqlindian.com/2012/07/06/deadlock-due-to-different-lock-granularity/)